# get values of checkboxes and put them in an input field using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get values of checkboxes when they are checked and put them in an input field.

I can do this using a button but like the example [shown HERE](http://www.overpie.com/jquery/articles/jquery-get-selected-checkboxes)

but what I need to do is to get the values of checkboxes once they are checked without using the button if that make sense.

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of a checkbox, add the value of the checkbox to the string and change the value of the textbox to the value of the string.

Use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to look through the checkboxes.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var string = "";
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            string += $(this).val();
        });
        $("#txtbox").val(string);
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PW98u/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".chk").click(function () {
                getValueUsingClass();
            });
        });

        function getValueUsingClass() {
            /* declare an checkbox array */
            var chkArray = [];

            /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
            $(".chk:checked").each(function () {
                chkArray.push($(this).val());
            });

            /* we join the array separated by the comma */
            var selected;
            selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

            /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
            if (selected.length > 1) {
                alert("You have selected " + selected);
            } else {
                alert("Please at least one of the checkbox");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="checkboxlist">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk">
            Value 1
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk">
            Value 2
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk">
            Value 3
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="4" class="chk">
            Value 4
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="5" class="chk">
            Value 5
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" />
</div>
```

```
var el = document.getElementById('checkboxes'),
    checkEls = [].slice.call(el.children);
el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var values = checkEls
        .filter(function(checkEl){
            return checkEl.checked;
        })
       .map(function(checkEl){
            return checkEl.value;
        });
    /* In ES6, just use
       var values = checkEls.filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.value);
    */
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DNk92/)